# How to analyse EEG files recorded from Brain Products V-Amp (Brain Vision Recorder)?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, eeg, p300, matlab

I have 3 files recorded from Brain Vision Recorder.

They are in the following formats:

1. `.eeg`
2. `.amrk`
3. `.ahdr`

I would like to analyse these data using EEGLAB. The trouble is that when I tried to load the `.eeg` file into EEGLAB (as a binary format), the eeg waves look completely distorted (in the eeg scroll option). I am new to eeg, so if someone could advise me on how to start analyzing these data (to look at simple P3 component would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: Would you mind a migration of this question to [Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/)? I asked a [meta-question](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/are-electrophysiology-questions-on-topic/157?noredirect=1#comment1376_157) there and they would welcome your question. It's definitely on-topic here, but I don't think you'll get an answer here.

Comment: Thank you @AliceD. I am not sure where to put this question in fact.

Comment: The SE network encourages to post questions only on one site. That's why I suggest migration.